# Dynamic console string colorization with XML?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, winforms, console

I have a console application with a Class like this:

```
Friend Class Documentation

    Friend Shared MyColor1 As ConsoleColor = 
        ConsoleColor.Yellow

    Private Shared ReadOnly ProcessName As String = 
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName

    Friend Shared ReadOnly Help As XElement =
<Help>

    <!-- Application Usage Examples -->
    <UsageExamples>
    [+] Usage examples:

        <%= ProcessName %> /Switch1=Value "C:\File.txt"
        {1}(Command explanation){1}
    </UsageExamples>

</Help>

End Class
```

There is a way to show the `(Command explanation)` string in a different consolecolor that I previouslly should set dynamically in a var?

So the idea is that instead of printing this:

http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/9795/90px.jpg

Do the necessary (and dynamically) modifications to the XML/Class above to set a color at specific position to print this else:

[image]

How I could manage this without immerse into a harder approach like coding a method that should parse and print the string to colorize it at specific char/keyword position or something else?

This is possibly to do in a easier and automated/dynamic way?

Any better ideas?

> UPDATE

This was my approach:

I've written a parser method to write colored text, which expects an string with delimiters.

```
''' <summary>
''' Writes colored text on the Console.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Text">Indicates the text to write.</param>
Friend Shared Sub WriteColoredText(ByVal Text As String)

    ' Store the current console colors to restore them later...
    Dim CurrentForegroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor
    Dim CurrentBackgroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.BackgroundColor

    Dim StringParts As String() = Text.Split({"{"c, "}"c})
    Dim PrintFlag As Boolean = False

    For Each str As String In StringParts

        If str Like "f#" OrElse str Like "f##" Then ' Change the ForeColor.
            PrintFlag = False
            Console.ForegroundColor = CInt(str.Replace(str.First, String.Empty))

        ElseIf str Like "b#" OrElse str Like "b##" Then ' Change the BackgroundColor.
            PrintFlag = False
            Console.BackgroundColor = CInt(str.Replace(str.First, String.Empty))

        ElseIf str Like "-f" Then  ' Restore the Forecolor.
            PrintFlag = False
            Console.ForegroundColor = CurrentForegroundColor

        ElseIf str Like "-b" Then ' Restore the BackgroundColor.
            PrintFlag = False
            Console.BackgroundColor = CurrentBackgroundColor

        Else ' Print the string as normal.
            PrintFlag = True

        End If

        If PrintFlag Then ' If it is not a '{fxx}/{bxx}/{-f}/{-b}' string then print the text.
            Console.Write(str)
        End If

    Next str

    ' Restore the original console colors.
    Console.BackgroundColor = CurrentBackgroundColor
    Console.ForegroundColor = CurrentForegroundColor

End Sub
```

Then with an XML with delimitters like this:

```
<!-- Application Usage Examples -->
<UsageExamples>
{f11}[+]{-f} {f14}Usage examples{-f}

    <%= ProcessName %> /Switch1=Value "C:\File.txt"
    {f11}( Command explanation ){-f}
</UsageExamples>
```

I can get an output like this, **but what I would like to do is simplify all of this to avoid the needs of a custom parser method written like my method avobe**, if that could be possibly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, (while there is any better idea) I did it following the approach that I mentioned on my question.

Enjoy this snippet!

```
' Name.......: HelpSection
' Author.....: Elektro
' Description: Class that manages the Help documentation of a Console application with colorization capabilities.
' Last Update: 05/01/2014
' References.: LINQ
' Indications: Use {FXX} as the start ConsoleColor ForeColor number, {-F} to restore the console forecolor.
'              Use {BXX} as the start ConsoleColor BackColor number, {-B} to restore the console BackColor.


#Region " Usage Examples "

#Region " Example 1 "

'Module Module1

'    Sub Main()

'        Console.Title = HelpSection.Help.<Title>.Value

'        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<Logo>.Value)
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<Separator>.Value)
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Executable name.......: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Process>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Application name......: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Name>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Application version...: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Version>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Application author....: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Author>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Application copyright.: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Copyright>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Author website........: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Website>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Author Skype..........: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Skype>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("    Author Email..........: {0}", HelpSection.Help.<Email>.Value))
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<Separator>.Value)
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<Syntax>.Value)
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<SyntaxExtra>.Value)
'        sb.AppendLine(HelpSection.Help.<UsageExamples>.Value)

'        HelpSection.WriteColoredTextLine(sb.ToString)
'        ' HelpSection.WriteColoredText(sb.ToString)

'        Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000)

'    End Sub

'End Module

#End Region

#Region " Example 2 "

' Individual Method Usage:
'
' HelpSection.WriteColoredText(" Hello World! ", ConsoleColor.Blue, ConsoleColor.Blue)
' HelpSection.WriteColoredTextLine(" Hello World! ", ConsoleColor.Magenta, ConsoleColor.Gray)

' HelpSection.WriteColoredText("{F10}Hello {F14}World!{-F}")
' HelpSection.WriteColoredTextLine("{B15}{F12} Hello World! {-F}{-B}")

#End Region

#End Region

#Region " ConsoleColor Enumeration Helper "

' Black = 0
' DarkBlue = 1
' DarkGreen = 2
' DarkCyan = 3
' DarkRed = 4
' DarkMagenta = 5
' DarkYellow = 6
' Gray = 7
' DarkGray = 8
' Blue = 9
' Green = 10
' Cyan = 11
' Red = 12
' Magenta = 13
' Yellow = 14
' White = 15

#End Region

#Region " HelpSection "

Friend Class HelpSection

#Region " Members "

    '''' <summary>
    '''' Indicates dynamically the name of the current process.
    '''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly ProcessName As String =
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName

    '''' <summary>
    '''' Use this var into an XML if need to escape an '>' character.
    '''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly c_GreaterThan As Char = ">"c

    '''' <summary>
    '''' Use this var into an XML if need to escape an '<' character.
    '''' </summary>
    Private ReadOnly c_LowerThan As Char = "<"c

#End Region

#Region " Help Text "

    Friend Shared ReadOnly Help As XElement =
<Help>

    <!-- Current process name -->
    <!-- That means even when the user manually changes the executable name -->
    <Process>{F10}<%= ProcessName %>{-F}</Process>

    <!-- Application title -->
    <Title>My Application .:: By Elektro ::.</Title>

    <!-- Application name -->
    <Name>{F10}My Application{-F}</Name>

    <!-- Application author -->
    <Author>{f10}Elektro{-F}</Author>

    <!-- Application version -->
    <Version>{F10}1.0{-F}</Version>

    <!-- Copyright information -->
    <Copyright>{F10}© Elektro Software 2014{-F}</Copyright>

    <!-- Website information -->
    <Website>{F10}http://foro.elhacker.net{-F}</Website>

    <!-- Skype contact information -->
    <Skype>{F10}ElektroStudios{-F}</Skype>

    <!-- Email contact information -->
    <Email>{F10}ElektroStudios@ElHacker.Net{-F}</Email>

    <!-- Application Logotype -->
    <Logo>{F11}
    .____                         
    |    |    ____   ____   ____  
    |    |   / _  \ / ___\ /  _ \ 
    |    |__( |_|  ) /_/  >  |_| )
    |_______ \____/\___  / \____/ 
            \/     /____/   
    {-F}</Logo>

    <!-- Separator shape -->
    <Separator>
    {F11}------------------------------------------------------>>>>{-F}
    </Separator>

    <!-- Application Syntax -->
    <Syntax>
    {F11}[+]{-F} {F14}Syntax{-F}

        <%= ProcessName %> {F10}(SWITCH){-F}={F10}(VALUE){-F} {F10}(IN FILE){-F}
    </Syntax>

    <!-- Application Syntax (Additional Specifications) -->
    <SyntaxExtra>
    {F11}[+]{-F} {F14}Switches{-F}

        {F10}/Switch1{-F}  | {F11}Description.{-F}
        {F10}/Switch2{-F}  | {F11}Description.{-F}
        {F10}        {-F}  |
        {F10}/?      {-F}  | {F11}Display this help.{-F}


    {F11}[+]{-F} {F14}Switch value types{-F}

        {F10}/Switch1{-F}  ({F11}INT{-F})
        {F10}/Switch2{-F}  ({F11}X,Y{-F})
    </SyntaxExtra>

    <!-- Application Usage Examples -->
    <UsageExamples>
    {F11}[+]{-F} {F14}Usage examples{-F}

        <%= ProcessName %> /Switch1=Value "C:\File.txt"
        {F11}( Command explanation ){-F}
    </UsageExamples>

</Help>

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Writes colored text on the Console.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Text">Indicates the color-delimited text to parse and then write.</param>
    Friend Shared Sub WriteColoredText(ByVal Text As String)

        ' Split the string to retrieve and parse the color delimitters.
        Dim StringParts As String() =
            Text.Split({"{"c, "}"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        ' If there is any string part to parse then Exit.
        If StringParts.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Store the current console colors to restore them later.
        Dim CurrentForegroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor
        Dim CurrentBackgroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.BackgroundColor

        ' A flag that indicates whether a string should be printed (to avoid color-delimitter prints).
        Dim PrintFlag As Boolean = False

        ' Parse the string parts
        For Each str As String In StringParts

            If str.ToLower Like "f#" _
            OrElse str.ToLower Like "f##" Then ' Change the ForeColor.

                PrintFlag = False
                Console.ForegroundColor = CInt(str.Replace(str.First, String.Empty))

            ElseIf str.ToLower Like "b#" _
            OrElse str.ToLower Like "b##" Then ' Change the BackgroundColor.

                PrintFlag = False
                Console.BackgroundColor = CInt(str.Replace(str.First, String.Empty))

            ElseIf str.ToLower Like "-f" Then  ' Restore the original Forecolor.

                PrintFlag = False
                Console.ForegroundColor = CurrentForegroundColor

            ElseIf str.ToLower Like "-b" Then ' Restore the original BackgroundColor.

                PrintFlag = False
                Console.BackgroundColor = CurrentBackgroundColor

            Else ' String is not a delimitter so we can print it.

                PrintFlag = True

            End If

            ' If it is not a delimitter like '{Fx}/{Bx}/{Fxx}/{Bxx}/{-F}/{-B}' then print the string part.
            If PrintFlag Then
                Console.Write(str)
            End If

        Next str

        ' Finish by restoring the original console colors.
        Console.BackgroundColor = CurrentBackgroundColor
        Console.ForegroundColor = CurrentForegroundColor

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Writes colored text on the Console.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Text">Indicates the text to write.</param>
    ''' <param name="ForeColor">Indicates the text color.</param>
    ''' <param name="BackColor">Indicates the background color.</param>
    Friend Shared Sub WriteColoredText(ByVal Text As String,
                                Optional ByVal ForeColor As ConsoleColor = Nothing,
                                Optional ByVal BackColor As ConsoleColor = Nothing)

        ' Store the current console colors to restore them later.
        Dim CurrentForegroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor
        Dim CurrentBackgroundColor As ConsoleColor = Console.BackgroundColor

        ' Set the new temporal console colors.
        Console.ForegroundColor = If(ForeColor = Nothing, CurrentForegroundColor, ForeColor)
        Console.BackgroundColor = If(ForeColor = Nothing, CurrentBackgroundColor, BackColor)

        ' Print the text.
        Console.Write(Text)

        ' Finish by restoring the original console colors.
        Console.ForegroundColor = CurrentForegroundColor
        Console.BackgroundColor = CurrentBackgroundColor

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Writes colored text on the Console and adds an empty line at the end.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Text">Indicates the color-delimited text to parse and then write.</param>
    Friend Shared Sub WriteColoredTextLine(ByVal Text As String)

        WriteColoredText(Text & Environment.NewLine)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Writes colored text on the Console and adds an empty line at the end.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Text">Indicates the color-delimited text to parse and then write.</param>
    ''' <param name="ForeColor">Indicates the text color.</param>
    ''' <param name="BackColor">Indicates the background color.</param>
    Friend Shared Sub WriteColoredTextLine(ByVal Text As String,
                                           Optional ByVal ForeColor As ConsoleColor = Nothing,
                                           Optional ByVal BackColor As ConsoleColor = Nothing)

        WriteColoredText(Text & Environment.NewLine, ForeColor, BackColor)

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```